# Criando o número do pedido

Tags: php

Bom dia !

Em um sistema de carrinho (loja virtual), qual é a forma mais usual para se criar o número do pedido? 
Lembrando que o usuário não precisa logar.

Aguardo.

Comment: Descreva com mais detalhes o seu cenário e seja mais especifico.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma chave criptografada usando as funções [hash()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.hash.php) e [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.microtime.php):

```
$codigo=hash('crc32',hash('sha512',microtime()));
```

Ele cria um `sha512` do `microtime()` e depois um `crc32` que é uma criptografia de menor tamanho, voce pode concluir com um [strtoupper()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtoupper.php) para manter um padrão maiúsculo.

Resumindo, você pode usar a criatividade desenrolar varias possibilidades para essa ampla situação.

Comment: Obrigado Wees Smith.